# Hot to change height of a responsive image without cutting its content?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need to change the heights of the image but to keep it responsive, keep the same width, and do not cut the content weirdly.

I try to add height property in my img section in HTML, but it is not working (do not change anything).

My code in HTML:

```
<section>
    <img src="me.jpg" alt="me" class="img-responsive center-block">
  </section>
```

Comment: try `width: 100%` for the image

Comment: everything is fine with the width and it is responsive, I need to change the height to be half of the browser page (now it is bigger that the page heights)

Comment: then try `height: 50vh`

Comment: Please show us the relevant CSS - including the height changing you are trying to do, and make your code into a working snippet. Are you trying to preserve the aspect ratio of the image or crop it to fit or stretch it to fit?

Answer (score 1):

this solved my issue

```
 <section>
      <img src="me.jpg" alt="me" width="600" height="435" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </section>
```

and CSS code

```
.img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid rgb(44,44,44);
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<section>
  <img src="me.jpg" alt="me" class="img-responsive center-block">
</section>
```

**CSS**
*You can add the width value you need, the vw is the percentage of the
device's width. This way you can make it responsive in through the X axis,
meaning it'll only change horizontally. And the height should be automatic so
it is adjusted according to the width and the original aspect.*

```
.img-responsive center-block {
   width: 20vw; 
   height: auto; 
}
```